# Ubuntu 22.04 settings gnome-control-center suddenly disappearing every time

Tags: gnome, software-center, gnome-settings-daemon

My gnome setting disappeared. In the beginning it was working fine but after some time it automatically disappeared. I tried to reinstall it using
**`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center`**
and it works fine until I reboot my system. After rebooting I need to reinstall every time.

The setting panel is disappearing every time. I don't understand what is the problem. Could someone please help me.

`Description:   Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`
`Release:       22.04`
`Codename:      jammy`

Ajit